# selenium-jupiter - How to set Firefox and Chrome options

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit5, selenium-jupiter

I need to run the same selenium tests with Firefox and Chrome, but I also need to set different options for them. Is that possible?

Running the same tests with both browsers is clearly possible, as is setting the options for just one of them. But when I try to set the options for both it doesn't seem to work.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as of Selenium-Jupiter 3.0.0, recently released. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/seljup/test/advance/SeveralOptionsJupiterTest.java).